# Ordering ggplot legend by the final value in a data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to re-order the elements in a legend, as they appear top to bottom in an R ggplot. That is: I'd like the order dictated by comparing the Y value at the right most point X axis point. In the following data, I'd like the legend to read from the top: bush, foo, baz, bar.

**Update**: following @alexwhan comments, I have added the data to the script.

**Update 2**: this is now exactly what I was hoping for, thanks to @thomas-kern on #R (bosie) irc.freenode. The trick was to add both, i.e.

```
 scale_linetype_discrete(breaks = ord$Variant) + scale_shape_discrete(breaks = ord$Variant)
```

Here's my R:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
require(grid)

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

lines <- "
X,Variant,Y
1,foo,123
1,bar,134
1,baz,135
1,bush,136
2,foo,221
2,bar,104
2,baz,155
2,bush,336
"

con <- textConnection(lines)
DF <- read.csv(con, header=TRUE)
close(con)
cdata <- ddply(DF, .(Variant,X), summarise, N = length(Y), mean=round(mean(Y),2), sd=round(sd(Y),2), se=round(sd(Y)/sqrt(length(Y)),2))

ord <- cdata[cdata$X == max(cdata$X),]
ord <- ord[order(ord$Variant, decreasing=T),]

pdf("out.pdf")

none <- element_blank()

bp <- ggplot(cdata, aes(x=X, y=mean, group=Variant)) + xlab("X label") + geom_line(aes(linetype=Variant)) + geom_point(aes(shape=Variant)) + ylab("Y Value") + labs(title = "mytitle") + scale_linetype_discrete(breaks = ord$Variant) + scale_shape_discrete(breaks = ord$Variant)

print(bp + theme(legend.justification=c(1,0), legend.position=c(1,0), legend.key.width=unit(3,"line"), legend.title=element_blank(), text = element_text(size=18))  + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', colour='black')) + theme(panel.grid.major = none, panel.grid.minor = none))

dev.off()
```

This generates exactly what I'm after:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really helps if you provide the data your plot is made with. Here's an example of how to approach with some data I made up:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = rnorm(8), group = rep(c("bar", "baz", "bush", "foo"), each = 2))
ord <- dat[dat$x == max(dat$x),]
ord <- ord[order(ord$y, decreasing=T),]
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(shape = group)) + geom_line(aes(group = group)) +
  scale_shape_discrete(breaks = ord$group)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! I have updated my question, this time with data and also your `ord` and `scale_shape_discrete` code. However, I'm looking for a plot that has different line types *and* different point types for each group. I'd like the line types and point types reflected in the legend. As is shown in my updated question, my attempt at this hast left me with two legends...

Comment: Actually, following more questions on #R on freenode, this is now solved. See the edits to my question.